# Warning in install.packages : packages ‘(‘rgdal’’, ‘repos=”http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin“)’ are not available (for R version 3.3.2)

Tags: r, macos

I have seen this question asked before and I know this is a repeat but after trying all the suggestions on how to get rgdal to work on a mac I still can't manage to install it properly. Some of its functions work but not all of it and I continually get the warning NOTE: rgdal::checkCRSArgs: no proj_defs.dat in PROJ.4 shared files. I have also tried to install this manually and upgrade rdgal but I've had no luck. I'm rather new to R so maybe I've missed something, but I'd be gratefull for any advice.

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to use that `repos` setting? Try again with `repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org"`.

Answer (score 0):

For those with similar problems the answer is to download homebrew a unix package installer for mac - ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" . Install it through terminal and then instal rgdal and its dependencies through terminal by typing  "brew install rgdal". The connection between proj4 and rgdal should be made.